# Composing one Gemfile from multiple others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile, squeel

I'm splitting a large application into multiple smaller ones. When doing this I realized that by creating a `Gemfile.global` and including it in both my main and sub applications I could clean up all of my `Gemfile`s. For example, all of my deployment gems go in the main `Gemfile`, and my rails goes in the `Gemfile.global`.

It works for pretty much all of my gems except one: Squeel.

My `Gemfile` in the root app starts off with:

```
gemfiles = [
  File.join('Gemfile.global'),
]
Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), gemfiles)) do |gemfile|
  eval(IO.read(gemfile), binding)
end

# gem 'squeel' # Let's try putting this in Gemfile.global
```

My `Gemfile.global` looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# rails and dependencies
gem 'squeel'
```

`bundle install` works great, as well as `rails s` and pretty much everything, the way you'd expect, with Squeel in the main `Gemfile`. Putting it in `Gemfile.global`, however, screws up the initialization process when using the default Squeel initializer:

```
Squeel.configure do |config|
end
```

`rails s` throws a `uninitialized constant Squeel (NameError)` even though `bundle install` reports `Using squeel (1.0.13)`. Why does this method of composing my `Gemfile` mess up the rails runtime constants?

Comment: After further inspection this totally screwed all of my gem's access to constants up. I'm back to the traditional way, but I'm curious as to why this happens/alternative approaches to composable Gemfiles.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you and I are running up against slightly different manifestations of the same phenomenon... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554397/rake-build-is-operating-in-an-incorrect-context

Comment: I think so. I'm about to dive into some of bundler's source this week, maybe I'll have an epiphany.

Comment: Right on - good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `eval_gemfile`:

```
gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile.global' ]
gemfiles.each do |gemfile|
  eval_gemfile gemfile
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `instance_eval` instead of `eval` when loading Gemfile.global into your Gemfile. i.e. your project Gemfile should look like below (removing File.joins to avoid confusion):

```
gemfiles = [ 'Gemfile.global' ]
gemfiles.each do |gemfile|
  instance_eval File.read(gemfile)
end
```